# Why are my marker icons shown, althoug using MarkerClusters?

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I'm using MarkerCluster only for **some** markers (the cameras with Symbol "Kame") with data from a *.geojson file:

```
function MarkerStyle(feature, latlng) {
  if (feature.properties.markerSymbol == null) {
    return L.marker(latlng).addTo(map);
  } else {
    var Ikon = feature.properties.markerSymbol.substring(0, 4);
    switch (Ikon) {
      case "none":
        var myIcon = L.divIcon({
          className: feature.properties.className, // zur Textausgabe
          html: feature.properties.text
        });
        return L.marker(latlng, { icon: myIcon }).addTo(map);
        break;
      case "Kame":
        var POI = L.marker(latlng, {
          icon: L.icon({
            iconUrl: "../img/".concat(feature.properties.markerSymbol),
            iconAnchor: [32, 32]
          })
        });
        var url = feature.properties.popupImage;
        POI.on("click", function(e) {
          BildZeigen(url, "Freifl&auml;che", 452, 802, 450, 800);
        });
        return POI.addTo(markers);
        break;
      default:
        return L.marker(latlng, {
          icon: L.icon({
            iconUrl: feature.properties.markerSymbol,
            className: feature.properties.className
          })
        }).addTo(map);
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Why is the grouping of the markers different, when zooming in and out again to same level? Why are marker icons shown very near to the clustering circle?
See map on [https://aachen-hat-energie.de/sonne/freiflaechenbild.htm]. Perhaps my markers are to large (64x64 pixel)?

Gruss, wonk

Answer (score 0):

thanks for putting the code in order, sorry, dummy.

I now found the error: the case "Kame" should not return the marker but:

```
    case "Kame":
    var POI = L.marker(latlng, {
      icon: L.icon({
        iconUrl: "../img/".concat(feature.properties.markerSymbol),
        iconAnchor: [32, 32]
      })
    });
    var url = feature.properties.popupImage;
    POI.on("click", function(e) {
      BildZeigen(url, "Freifl&auml;che", 452, 802, 450, 800);
    });
    POI.addTo(markers);
    return;
    break;
```